# Splunk regex query returning no results

Tags: regex, splunk

I've a pretty simple regex:

```
A route named '[a-zA-Z]+' is already in the route collection
```

and I've tested it on Debuggex and it works under `PCRE`:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/SM98phQL5cpsn-Uo)

But it won't return any results in Splunk when I provide this query:

```
| regex _raw="(?=A route named '[a-zA-Z]+' is already in the route collection)"
```

Per the [Splunk documentation](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/5.0.5/SearchReference/Regex), it's required that I group the entire expression so I am. What's more, when I run this query in Splunk:

```
A route named is already in the route collection
```

it does return results, so the data is there.

Can somebody tell me why this won't work in Splunk?

Comment: did you try "rex" rather than "regex" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I figured it out. When searching with the `regex` command you have to supply some sort of query prior to it, for example:

```
* | regex _raw="(A route named '[a-zA-Z]+' is already in the route collection)"
```

take note to the `*` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use this lookahead, you just need a simple group :

```
| regex _raw="(A route named '[a-zA-Z]+' is already in the route collection)"
```

Using the lookahead, you're searching for... nothing. But nothing followed by your sentence.

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't return any results. I am using Splunk 5.0.5; maybe there is some oddity that I'm missing in the query?

Comment: I'm missing something... You said "data is here" for the `A route named is already in the route collection` query. But there no route specified in this sentence, right? It can't be caught by the current regex?

Comment: Right, so if I run a basic query with all the terms *except* the name of the route, the logs are found, but the regex (even though it works; verified via Debuggex) is not pulling anything back in Splunk. Even as you provided it.

Comment: Have you got an example of a route name which should be caught? And you could try `| regex _raw="(A route named)"` to check if regex search works.

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of the Splunk regex command is to capture *something* into a field. And your syntax is incorrect: you're not capturing anything. A lookahead simply does just that, look-ahead.

Splunk regex reference: http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex

Note: _raw is the default field anyways!

In your [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/SM98phQL5cpsn-Uo), you're trying to capture *HelloWorld*:

> A route named 'HelloWorld' is already in the route collection

You want to save *HelloWorld* somewhere into a field, correct?

> > * | rex "named '(?[\']+)' is" | search route=*

So, what this search does, is look for your logs and extracts values for routes if available. The following pipe filters for only logs that return an extracted route value.

So long as there's no 's as part of the name, you can cover any syntax as part the route name.

Let me know if this works for you.